# CSS Nth Selector - unexpected result

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div id="quicklinks">
    <div class="sidenav-header">
        <h3>Quick Links</h3>
    </div>

    <a href="/link-to-page-one">Link One</a>
    <a href="/link-to-page-two">Link Two</a>
</div>
```

In the above code I have two links. It seems to address the style of the second link in this code block I am having to target the 3rd element. My CSS is addressing the `<a>` tag though

```
#quicklinks {
    height:120px;
}
#quicklinks a {
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    background:#92d050;
    margin:6px 12px;
    padding:10px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#quicklinks a:nth-child(3) {
    background:#ff9900;
}
```

Why is my `nth-child` set to #3 to effect the 2nd a element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child(3)` is selecting the third child element of any type, including your `<div class="sidenav-header">` element. You should use `a:nth-of-type(2)` to select the 2nd child element of type `a`

Comment: Seems odd that the <a> is being declared, so it seems a type is already being chosen. Is it just ignoring the a declaration in the class name? Thank you @lambo477 for your response.

Comment: "The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent." http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp. So, for example, if you  used the CSS Selector `a:nth-child(1)`, no HTML element would be selected - simply because there isn't an anchor element which is the first child of its parent. Does that make sense @Groovefactory?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, just wondering whose idea it was to make that the default behavior, lol, I see now where they covered the scenarios with these variations on the selectors. Thanks again.

Comment: Agreed - not necessarily the most intuitive CSS selector